# Cannot get Chart.js working

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js

Looking to use chart.js but cannot get a simple example working.

Using the docs I tried this: http://jsfiddle.net/hhuojv5m/

Backup code:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="500px" height="200"></canvas>

$(function(){
// Get context with jQuery - using jQuery's .get() method.
var ctx = $("#myChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
// This will get the first returned node in the jQuery collection.
var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx);
var data = {
labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
datasets: [
    {
        label: "My First dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
    },
    {
        label: "My Second dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
    }
]
};
});
```

But this doesnt work, any help? No graph is shown at all as per the fiddle.

Comment: Your id for `canvas` is `canvas` but you're getting `#myChart` using jQuery.

Comment: You need to have the browser console **open** when you're looking for bugs. You would have seen the error reported from the above-mentioned problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to actually call one of the chart types. You have that dataset object declared and initialized but you're not passing it to anything!

Assuming that's supposed to be a line chart, you need to call

```
myNewChart.Line(data);
```

And you need to fix the problem with the `<canvas>` id. [Fixed fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/echpLLdq/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<title>ChartJS - Few Chart Examples Using Chart engine Libs</title>

    <script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Chart.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Line<br/>Pie<br/>Radar_Chart <br/> using chartJS libs <br/> <bl/> To display uncomment the drawing line in Index.html</p>
    <canvas id="mycanvas" width="256" height="356">     </canvas>
    <canvas id="mycanvas2" width="956" height="356">   </canvas>                
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var ctx = $("#mycanvas").get(0).getContext("2d");           
        var ctx = document.getElementById("mycanvas2").getContext("2d");    
        var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx);                                                               
        var datas = {
        labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],

            datasets: [
            {
            //gray with red circle 
        label: "My First dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "red",
        pointHighlightFill: "red",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data:  [16,25,13,12,45,16,56,16,75]
            },
            {
            //blue progress/line 
        label: "My Second dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        data: [6,5,43,2,45,6,76,76,45]
            }
            ]
        };  

var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(datas);
```

Comment: Include Jquery-2.1.3.min.js and chart.js to your project and then follow this code, then you will be able to get it to display.